# Write bits sequences from threads in order

Tags: c, multithreading, binary, openmp, bit-shift

I have parallel program. On each thread a have a sequence of bits stored in a char*. 
My brains gets seg fault when I am thinking how to write this bits in a file. The bits from 1st thread then the bits from the second and so on without the 0s need to have full bytes.

I an example will be very usefull. The data **is not** this small it can be 100MB 
thread 1: 13 bits 1011 1111 0110 0(000)  because i can't store 13 bits i can store 2 bytes
thread 2: 9 bits 1001 1011 0(000 0000)
thread 3: 7 bits 1011 111(0) 
thread 4: 5 bits 0001 1(000)

**Question:**
How can I can I get the end result in a file or char* as this? 
1011 1111 0110 0100 1101 1010 1111 1000 11(00 0000)

If it helps i can put \' when the bits come from a different thread
1011 1111 0110 0'100 1101 10'10 1111 1'000 11(00 0000)

Comment: You didn't really ask a question. A file is, by definition, a stream of bytes.

Comment: The data is small enough, you can probably pass it all to one collector who writes the file.  Else you can have a token that starts at thread 1, and once he writes, he passes the token to thread 2... Here, token can just be a message used to synchronize the writes...or a shared variable that is only written by a thread when it's current value matches the thread number.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do file I/O directly from the threads, as that would not do any synchronization and things would not end up in the proper order.

If you know in advance how many bits each thread can generate, I would just pre-allocate the storage in the parent process, and hand each thread its working area. Then when the threads have joined, the parent process can write out the data in the proper order.

Comment: lets say i know exactly the number of bits generated by each thread. I am not sure if i can shift easily the sequence of bits (not just 8 bits, but hundreds of bytes) or i should keep the first bits from thread 2 that fill the gap from thread 1 and the other bits from thread 2 in bytes